# Tabular data structure modification in python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, tabular

My query had two parts. So, I have a data in the following format, where my target field is ‘Groups’.
Stage 1:

| ID | Income | Owns_Car | Family_size | Groups |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 65153 | Yes | 1 | "A","C","D" |
| 2 | 78965 | No | 2 | "B","D","E" |
| 3 | 65465 | Yes | 5 | "A","D","F" |

I would want to build a multinomial classification model, for which I want to have the data formatted like this.

Stage 2:

| ID | Income | Owns_car | Family_size | Groups |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 65153 | Yes | 1 | A |
| 1 | 65153 | Yes | 1 | C |
| 1 | 65153 | Yes | 1 | D |
| 2 | 78965 | No | 2 | B |
| 2 | 78965 | No | 2 | D |
| 2 | 78965 | No | 2 | E |
| 3 | 65465 | Yes | 5 | A |
| 3 | 65465 | Yes | 5 | D |
| 3 | 65465 | Yes | 5 | F |

Once I have built the model and have assigned probabilities, I would like to assign the probability into a group per ID like this.

Stage 3:

| ID | Income | Owns_Car | Family_size | Groups | Probability |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 65153 | Yes | 1 | "A","C","D" | 1,0,0 |
| 2 | 78965 | No | 2 | "B","D","E" | 1,1,0 |
| 3 | 65465 | Yes | 5 | "A","D","F" | 1,0,1 |

I am not being able to build the loop or function in order to go from stage 1 to stage 2 and back to stage 3. any tips or code snippets for anything done similar?

Comment: Is the first value in the Groups column a string: '"A","C","D"'?

Comment: Yes. Its a group of text entries in that manner. That means ID 1 is mapped to Groups A,C and D

Comment: I think you want to remove (`replace`) the " characters and then use `split` (these are both functions on the `str` series accessor) to turn your strings into lists of the form ["A", "B", "D"], and then use `pandas.DataFrame.explode`  https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html

Comment: Thanks. pandas.DataFrame.explode should work if I keep the other columns as fixed. Any suggestions on how to put the column values for a single ID into a row, single cell (Stage 3)?

Comment: I'd try a groupby on 'id' and apply a function which returns the first row but replaces the Groups value using 'pandas.Series.to_list’ and a string join. Not sure where the probabilities come into it but I imagine it can be handled the same way.

Comment: if you have single string `'"A","C","D"` then first you have to conver to list `["A", "B", "D"]` and later use `explode`. As for assinging probability - keep original dataset with lists/string `["A", "B", "D"]` and assign `probability` to this dataset.